# CSS Transform Issue

Tags: html, jquery, css, firefox

I am having the strangest issue in Firefox. When I click to flip one of the cards at eh bottom, I only see half of the back in Firefox. Safari and Chrome are good, it's just Firefox.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

https://www.cbnew.whitehotstaging.com/

```
.back {
   font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180.1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180.1deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(180.1deg);
     -o-transform: rotateY(180.1deg);
    transform: rotateY(180.1deg);
     text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 50px 60px 0px 60px;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Change `transform: rotateY(180.1deg);` to `transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotateY(180.1deg);` and see if anything changes. This forces the browser to use better graphic engine to render the element.

Comment: Please edit your question so that the information is available without having to click on links

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `backface-visibility: hidden` to the `.filpper` div.